# Adding headers via HttpInterceptor Angular 5

Tags: angular5

I want to add headers to post request from Angular 5 web app.
I've created the following Injectable class, registered in my app module:

```
@Injectable()
    export class headerInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
      intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {    
        // Clone the request to add the new header         
        const authReq = req.clone({
          headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type':  'application/json; charset=utf-8',        
          })
        });        
        return next.handle(authReq);


      }
    }
```

I have network communication service and Im adding body parameters as below.

```
@Injectable()
export class NetworkService {

  Root:string = 'some valid url';
  results:Object[];
  loading:boolean;

  // inject Http client to our client service.
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient ) {

  }



  login(loginParams : URLSearchParams){    
    let baseURL = `${this.Root}/login`;                    
    this.httpClient.post(baseURL, JSON.stringify({'UserName':'123','Password':'123'} ))
    .subscribe(data => {
        console.log();
    },
    err => {
          console.log('Error: ' + err.error);
      });
```

when I put breakpoint after the clone method inside headerInterceptor class I can see the request body. 
the problem is when I switch to network tab in chrome, I get 405 error and I can't see the body and the new headers. when I return the original request 'req' 
the body sent ok but no new headers of course.

Comment: have you added that interceptor to providers array in app module?

Comment: yes: {
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: headerInterceptor, 
    multi: true         
  }

Comment: why the `const`?

Comment: no must, but its not the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was on server side I'm using ASP.net and wcf.
it seems that the server must implement CORS support when working with Angular 5 project (works ok with jQuery and cross domain tag).

this post helped me to add support in CORS:

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/idof/2011/07/02/cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-and-wcf/

Answer (score 5):

App Module,

```
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { headerInterceptor } from './httpinterceptor'
```

Add it to providers,

```
providers: [
{
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: headerInterceptor,
    multi: true
}
],
```

Now change the intereptor to, I have changed the way `headers` are added

```
@Injectable()
    export class headerInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
      intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const authReq = req.clone({
              headers:req.headers.set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
        });
        return next.handle(authReq);
      }
    }
}
```

You can also use `setHeaders`:

```
@Injectable()
export class headerInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor() {}
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {y
    req = req.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
      }
    });
    return next.handle(req);
  }
}
```

Comment: @Savaran, your answer is correct  but my problem was sever side.

Comment: yeah its fine, the final outcome should be you should get an answer and I m happy that its solved for you. :-)